# Что означает Promise<UserMOdel>?

Tags: typescript, nestjs

Есть такой код на сервере async `validateUser(dto: AuthDto): Promise<UserModel> {[что-то]}`

Что означает `Promise<UserModel>`?

То что в случае успеха вернётся UserModel. Верно?

Comment: Да. нужно ещё 11 символов...

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/promise